# video object linked list insert function

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

trying to create link list for video object to insert, remove, lookup, print. having an error with insert function

main.cpp:50:25: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
       list.insert(Video *video);
                         ^

main.cpp

```
int main (){

 23   int counter = 0;
 24   string command;
 25   Vlist list;
 26   Video *video;

 29   while (getline(cin, command))
 30   {
 31     if(command=="insert")
 32     {
 33       getline(cin, title);
 34       getline(cin, url);
 35       getline(cin, comment);
 36       cin >> length;
 37       cin >> rating;
 38       cin.ignore();
 39 

 46       list.insert(Video *video);
 47       counter++;
 48     }
 49     else if(command=="remove")
 50     {
 51       getline(cin, url);
 52       getline(cin, comment);
 53       cin >> length;
 54       cin >> rating;
 55       cin.ignore();
 56     }
```

created node constructor with video object passed in parameter

videolist.h

```
 5 #include <iostream>
  6 #ifndef VLIST_H
  7 #define VLIST_H
  8 #include <string>
  9 #include "video.h"
 10 
 11 using namespace std;
 12 
 13 class Vlist
 14 {
 15   public:
 16     Vlist();
 17     void insert(Video *video);
 18     void insert_end();
 19     void print();
 20 
 21 private:
 22     class Node
 23     {
 24       public:
 25         Node(Video *video, Node *next)
 26         {
 27           m_video=video; m_next=next;}
 28         Video* m_video;
 29         Node *m_next;
 30     };
 31 
 32    Node *m_head;
 33 
 34 };
 35 #endif
```

videolist.cpp

```
28 void Vlist::insert(Video *video)
 29 {
 30 
 31 if(m_head==NULL)
 32   {
 33     m_head=new Node(video, NULL);
 34   }
 35   else
 36   {
 37     Node *ptr=m_head;
 38     while(video->get_title()>ptr->m_next -> m_video-> get_title())
 39     {
 40       ptr=ptr->m_next;
 41     }
 42     ptr->m_next=new Node(video*, ptr->m_next);
 43   }
 44 
 45 
 46 }
```

video.h

```
  5 #ifndef VIDEO_H //if not define
  6 #define VIDEO_H
  7   
  8 #include<iostream>
  9 #include<string>
 10 
 11 using namespace std;
 12 
 13 class Video
 14 {
 15   public: 
 16     Video(string title , string url, string comment, double length, int rating);
 17     ~Video();
 18     void print();
 19     bool longest_length(Video *smallest);
 20     bool largest_rating(Video *smallest);
 21     bool title_order(Video *smallest);
 22     string get_title();
 23   
 24 
 25   private:
 26 
 27     double m_length;
 28     int m_rating;
 29     string m_title;
 30     string m_comment;
 31     string m_url;
 32 
 33 };
 34 #endif 
 35
```

video.cpp

```
 64 string Video::get_title()
 65 {
 66   return m_title;
 67 }
```

Comment: You really don't need to show so much code for a compile time error. And you said the error is in **main.cpp:50 25**, that's the line number, right? But you didn't post that line...

Comment: i fixed the code and placed the right part of the code

Answer (score 1):

```
list.insert(Video *video);
```

is wrong, it should be

```
list.insert(*video);
```

to have a correct syntax. But looking at your implementation of VList, you are taking a pointer to a video, so

```
list.insert(video);
```

is probably what you are looking for.

Your compiler error explains this quite well, you should get used to looking at this kind of message closely.

I think the line numbers in the code you posted are a little off.